# Android app not Responding in Background when trying to get HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am having an issue, when I try to update some information in the background in my app I constantly get reports of ANR (Are not responding).

The code block is as follows

```
    class getServerTime extends AsyncTask<String, Long, Long> {
private Long getInternetData() {

    String sURL = "http://crystalmathlabs.com/tracker/api.php?type=time"; //just a string

    // Connect to the URL using java's native library
    HttpURLConnection connect = null;
    try {
        int responseCode = -1;

        List<String> listSet = new ArrayList();
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connect.setConnectTimeout(R.integer.timeoutLengthWithACapitalT);
        connect.setReadTimeout(R.integer.timeoutLengthWithACapitalT);
        connect.connect();  //this is the timeout line
        responseCode = connect.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode < 400) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                listSet.add(inputLine);
            in.close();
            if (listSet.get(0) != null)
                return Long.parseLong(listSet.get(0));
        }
        return -1L;
    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("getServerTime", "File Not Found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("getServerTime", "Unknown Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if (connect != null)
            connect.disconnect();
    }

    return -1L;
}

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(String[] params) {
    Long response;
    new Scores();
    try {
        response = getInternetData();
        if (response != null) {
                return response;
        }
        return -1L;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error in getServerTime", "" + Log.getStackTraceString(e.getCause().getCause()));
    }

    return -1L;
}
```

}

On connect.connect I receive timeouts.

Attached below are two examples of the ANR reports, I simply can't figure this out, please help!

https://pastebin.com/F7iZ267D
https://pastebin.com/W1eSdH4F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at android.os.AsyncTask.get (AsyncTask.java:507)
>     at
>   com.yargonauts.burk.runescapemarketwatch.crystalMathLabs.a.a
>   (crystalMathFunctions.java:30)

You are calling `AsyncTask.get()`, this pretty much negates the use of an asynctask since it blocks the thread until the async task is done.
This blocking causes the ANR since the main thread is stuck waiting for the result.

You need to override the `onPostExecute(Result)` method and perform the follow-up work there. Check out the `Usage` section of the asynctask javadoc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Is it safe to call an async task from an async task? Because the reason I blocked the thread is because I needed the result before proceeding.

Comment: That simply means you are trying to use an asynchronous technique in a synchronous manner. The asynchronous approach is to define what to do when the result becomes available (`onPostExecute` for AsyncTask) instead of directly retrieving the result. Trying to use asynchronous code in a synchronous manner will make you have a bad time.

Comment: You have saved my bacon! Thank you very much, I've been trying to solve this forever!